# HighCharts - Permanent tooltip on solid gauge

Tags: highcharts

So, I'm using Highcharts'solidgauge-chart as a circular progress bar. It's working very nicely except for one thing; tooltips. I'd love to have the tooltip permanently inside the chart as shown on the image, but I can't seem to find anything on the API and documentation, or Google for that matter, that'd help me set it visible permanently. Right now I need to hover my cursor on top of it which, for my purpose, isn't ideal.

I'm using solidgauge-type simply because I couldn't find a more fitting type for this and I just wanted to stick with Highcharts.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

[Solid gauge -chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbTa7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dataLabels` to display the wanted value inside the solidgauge chart.

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Speed',
    data: [80],
    dataLabels: {
      y: -20,
      borderWidth: 0,
      useHTML: true,
      format: '<div style="text-align:center">' +
        '<span style="font-size:25px">{y}</span><br/>' +
        '<span style="font-size:12px;opacity:0.4">km/h</span>' +
        '</div>'
    },
  }]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g724szmc/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.dataLabels

Comment: Damn. I tried the data labels but I had no idea they can be styled. What a nice, easy solution. Thank you very much!